# eBay Finding API get completed listings sort by whether ended with sales

Tags: ebay-api, listings

Trying to get completed listings with sales from eBay API. I can get the list of all 'ended listings', however, having troubles determining, whether the listing had any sales. What I am currently using to determine it is

```
item->sellingStatus->sellingState;
```

even though according to eBay API documentation that is exactly what I need, the response never matches manual search on eBay..

If an item is listed as good til cancelled and it had sales, but is still running (and will be running continuously), the response for this listing is `EndedWithoutSales`, which makes no sense - first of all, it is not ended yet, second of all, it already had sales..

What I need is a reliable way to sort completed listings into those listings, which had at least one sale (regardless whether the listing is still running as good til cancelled or already ended) and those listings, which ended with no sales.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try [the eBay Developer Support site](https://go.developer.ebay.com/dev-help-center)

Comment: thanks! found it there. seems like in the response the timeframe is restricted to 14 days, and on ebay website - no

Answer (score 0):

I am using GetMyeBaySellingRequest to get my sale numbers i.e last 24 hours ended listings which are sold.

```
<SellingSummary><Include>TRUE</Include></SellingSummary>
<SoldList>
    <DurationInDays>1</DurationInDays>
    <OrderStatusFilter>All</OrderStatusFilter>
    <Pagination>
      <EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    </Pagination>
</SoldList>
```

Hence under the SellingSummary part i received all the required data. Here [TotalSoldCount] depends on the SoldList > DurationInDays.

```
[ActiveAuctionCount] => 56
[AuctionSellingCount] => 13697
[AuctionBidCount] => 59
[TotalAuctionSellingValue] => 724.44
[TotalSoldCount] => 32
[TotalSoldValue] => 477.97
[SoldDurationInDays] => 1
[ClassifiedAdCount] => 0
[TotalLeadCount] => 0
[ClassifiedAdOfferCount] => 0
[TotalListingsWithLeads] => 0
[QuantityLimitRemaining] => 54852
[AmountLimitRemaining] => 4.845525842E7
```

Hope it helps.